# Parsing URL with hashes

Tags: url, segments

Have this URL:

```
http://192.168.1.2/univsched#/csf
```

How can I parse this using EE tags? I want the value: csf

segment_x tags don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved it by using the javascript

```
window.location.hash.substr(2);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I believe EE actually throws this value away, and it should.
The hash is a front end display feature for your browser, not a url.

Use it for javascript and scroll-to positions on a page.

You should re-think why you need to be using the hash in the first place.